# defining 2D array in c in VS Express 2012

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()//this is the way that we pragram in c
{
  int arr[][]={{1,2},{1,2},{1,3}};//in class it wasnt required to initialize both
}
```

the errors:

> Error 1   error C2087: 'arr' : missing subscript
>   Error 2   error C2078: too many initializers
>   3 IntelliSense: an array may not have elements of this type

I am a beginner , and i saw in class that the professor did the same thing.
also i asked my instructor and he told me that it should raise this error.

can someone please addres me to where and what is the problem?

Comment: Your declaration is missing a **type**: `int arr[][] = ....`

Comment: Also, **`int main(void)`**

Comment: Also commas... also you need to specify dimensions for others but last

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the type; all but the first dimension must be specified; and you're missing commas between the aggregate initializers. Working example:

```
int main(void) {
    int arr[][2] = {{1,2}, {1,2}, {1,3}};
}
```

Comment: I edited the question as i wrote it in the program...Cant I not initialize the rows and colums?

Answer (score 1):

When you have such a declaration

```
int arr[][]={{1,2},{1,2},{1,3}};
```

then the compiler can determine the number of the elements for the left most dimension. There are three initializers so the left most dimension is equal to 3. However the compiler is unable to determine the number of elements in the right most dimension because all these declarations are valid

```
int arr[][2]={{1,2},{1,2},{1,3}};
int arr[][20]={{1,2},{1,2},{1,3}};
int arr[][200]={{1,2},{1,2},{1,3}};
```

So you need explicitly to specify the number of elements in the right most dimension of the array. As I can guess you mean the following array declaration

```
int arr[][2]={{1,2},{1,2},{1,3}};
```

that is equivalent to

```
int arr[3][2]={{1,2},{1,2},{1,3}};
```

Though the MS VS allows a declaration of main like

```
void main()
```

nevertheless according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

even if a rerun statement is absent.

Answer (score 0):

You should add type to your array declaration - for example int arr[][].
If you don't want to specify size of columns and rows you have to do it dynamically. For example this way:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int r = 3, c = 4, i, j, count;

    int **arr = (int **)malloc(r * sizeof(int *));
    for (i=0; i<r; i++)
         arr[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));

    // Note that arr[i][j] is same as *(*(arr+i)+j)
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
         arr[i][j] = ++count;  // OR *(*(arr+i)+j) = ++count

    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
         printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);

   /* Code for further processing and free the 
      dynamically allocated memory */

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: i added the type in the program , i forgot to write them in the question.

Comment: I've edited my answer following your question about predefined sizes of given dimensions